# Haskell Stack doesnt work correctly on OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, haskell, haskell-stack

I can't get haskell's stack to work on my Mac.

I installed haskell by:
`brew cask install haskell-platform`

Which is specified here: https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html#osx-homebrewcask

I've also tried installing via the downloadable package at the same site.

I do the following commands:

`stack new my-project
cd my-project
stack setup
stack build
stack exec my-project-exe`

Per the documentation here:
https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#quick-start-guide

And I immediately see this:
`[1]    43017 killed     stack exec my-project-exe`

I've also tried many other ways of installing haskell. I've actually been able to get something compiled and executed just using `cabal`, but I can't then get `hlint`, `hindent`, or `ghc-mod` to work, they all return a similar message to the one above. I'd love to be able to work with HaskForce in IntelliJ on my Mac, but I've never had luck getting haskell to work.

#### System Specs

- macOS 10.12.6 (16G29) (Sierra)
- Fresh uninstall/reinstall of XCode (accepted terms)
- brew as package manager

Here's a gif of what happens as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P95g1.jpg

## UPDATE

I blew away all stuff related to ghc, stack, and cabal and then installed this way
https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Writing the little HelloWorld.hs script worked fine and showed `Hello, World`

However, doing

`stack new someproj
cd someproj
stack build`

Resulted in this:

```
➜  someproj stack build
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /Users/trevord2/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /Users/trevord2/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /Users/trevord2/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /Users/trevord2/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.o )
Linking /Users/trevord2/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 ...
someproj-0.1.0.0: configure (lib + exe)
Configuring someproj-0.1.0.0...
someproj-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library someproj-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Lib              ( src/Lib.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Lib.o )
Preprocessing executable 'someproj-exe' for someproj-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/someproj-exe/someproj-exe-tmp/Main.o )
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/someproj-exe/someproj-exe ...
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/trevord2/someproj/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/libHSsomeproj-0.1.0.0-6corWoTDCA69pE1sqNF8Id.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/trevord2/someproj/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/libHSsomeproj-0.1.0.0-6corWoTDCA69pE1sqNF8Id.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_someprojzm0zi1zi0zi0zm6corWoTDCA69pE1sqNF8Id_Lib_someFunc1_closure", referenced from:
      _Main_main1_info in Main.o
      _S39Z_srt in Main.o
  "_someprojzm0zi1zi0zi0zm6corWoTDCA69pE1sqNF8Id_Lib_someFunc1_info", referenced from:
      _Main_main_info in Main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

--  While building package someproj-0.1.0.0 using:
      /Users/trevord2/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build lib:someproj exe:someproj-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Which I've seen before and was actually one of my initial problems

### UPDATE 2: Created GitHub Issue

Here's the issue: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3487

After talking with folks on #haskell IRC they recommended I create an issue as this is very peculiar behaviour from what I understand. I'll try make sure whatever we find out here is pushed up there too.

Comment: Get started like this: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Comment: Thanks @Sibi I tried that and got this linker error

Comment: Just to be sure that the correct commandline-tools are used. In Terminal.app do `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app` (I assume Xcode is installed in the default location).